# A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter with readonly property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I know there's a lot of question about this error, but I haven't found anyone which solves this scenario:

I've a readonly property and inside a method I want to use it (not assign it) so the solution to the error can't be the typical one:

```
var a = myOjb.MyProp;
DoSomething(a);
myObj.MyProp = a;
```

Because that code won't compile such as MyProp is readonly and cannot be assigned.

Basically what I want is to write the Stream of Response property in a method like this:

```
public ActionResult Guardar()
{
    try
    {
        SomeMethod(ref Response.OutputStream);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", name));
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        return null;
    }
    catch { }
}

public void SomeMethod(ref Stream responseStream)
{
    responseStream.Write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 5, 3 }, 0, 4);
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks, Diego

*Note*: The code is just an example.

Comment: Passing a variable by reference, means you *want* to change it and, when you do that, you want to make sure that the variable you pass at the point you call the method is changed and not a copy of it *if* the variable you pass is not a reference type. So, it is only normal that you should not be able to pass a readonly variable as a ref. In addition, when a variable is a property, it is, in essence, a method. Passing a property as a ref is like passing the result of a method as a ref which cannot be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the parameter to a normal parameter.

You (probably) don't need a `ref` parameter anyway.

For more information on passing by reference, see [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

---

If you really need to have a `ref` parameter, you can put the object in a local writable variable, and pass that variable as `ref`.
However, this will defeat the entire purpose of the parameter.

Comment: Thansk for the link. An interesting and useful read. I think what I took away from it most is that I (personally, not as a global fact) very very rarely (if ever) want to use ref. :)

Comment: @Chris: Exactly.  `ref` should almost never be used with reference types.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to make this a reference parameter to do what you want.  just pass in the stream and write to it.

It complains because you are using a ref parameter and passing the `Response.OutputStream`, which means that when your method returns it *may* try to set `Response.OutputStream` to a new stream from within the method, which is not allowed.  It doesn't mean it *will* do, but it might.

for example this would be valid in your example (and is why the compiler complains):

```
public void SomeMethod(ref Stream responseStream)
{
    responseStream = new Stream();
    responseStream.Write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 5, 3 }, 0, 4);
}
```

and would attempt to assign a new stream object to the `Response.OutputStream` which would not be allowed.